# Check types of components passed as props in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, frontend

I have a question related to type checking in React components passed as props: **How can we do type checking to ensure we are passing as props only allowed components?**

Let me illustrate it. We have the component we want to pass around:

```
type DummyProps = {
  name: string;
};

const Dummy = ({ name }: DummyProps) => {
  return (<div>{name}</div>);
}
```

And the component we want to inject the `Dummy` component to (and have static type checking, so we cannot pass any other one):

```
type DummyWrapperProps = {
  dummy: ReactComponentElement<typeof Dummy>;
};

const DummyWrapper = ({ dummy }: DummyProps) => {
  return (<div>{name}</div>);
}
```

Now, if we call `DummyWrapper`, despite having explictly set the type of its `dummy` prop to `ReactComponentElement<typeof Dummy>`, it seems we can pass any ReactElement no matter what props/type it has:

```
const dummyElement = <Dummy name='dummy' />
const otherElement = <Other /> //this component is defined elsewhere

<DummyWrapper dummy={dummyElement} /> // This works
<DummyWrapper dummy={otherElement} /> // This also works
```

I have also tried to do similar things having `DummyWrapperProps` being defined with `React.ReactElement`, `React.FC` etc. but always get the same results: typescript static type checking does not warn about components/elements being passed not matching expected type.

I assume the issue also extends to `children` because it's basically the same thing: you are passing around elements.

Lastly, I know I could do some kind of dynamic type checking, reading properties of the node the component is receiving, but as I say I want to do type checking on compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can not do this in that way, because any element instantiation type will be `JSX.Element` and probably you can do this instead:

```js
const DummyWraper = ({ dummy: D, name }: { dummy: FC<DummyProps> } & DummyProps) => (
  <div>
    <D name={name} />
  </div>
)
```

Resulting:

```js
type DummyProps = {
  name: string
}

const Other: FC<{ some: number }> = () => <div>1</div>

const Dummy: FC<DummyProps> = ({ name }) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>
}

const dummyElement = <Dummy name="dummy" />
const otherElement = <Other />

const b = <DummyWraper dummy={Other} name="dummy" />
const c = <DummyWraper dummy={Dummy} name="dummy" />
```

Beware of `FC<{}>` type for `Other` because `{}` in typescript works like `any` for objects

Comment: Thanks :) Ok, understand! So what you are suggesting is passing around the functional component and its props so we "instantiate" it inside the DummyWrapper component. I think this is very similar to just passing DummyProps into the DummyWrapper and may be easier at the end. You'll end up with the same thing: controlling which component will be rendered inside DummyWrapper.